# Can't force pregnant women to work

Tags: fallout-shelter

Basically, when a dweller becomes pregnant, I can usually send them back to their work stations from the Residence room. For some reason, that doesn't apply to all of them, since sometimes they get stuck in said Residence room, i.e. I'm not able to select them and drag them to a different room as the green silhouette (that appears when you drag dwellers around) disappears as soon as I drag it (but is still there if I just hold my finger over said pregnant dweller). What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sometimes happens. The two main workarounds are:

- Exit to the main menu and re-enter the vault
- Force them to leave the room by assigning 2/4/6 other people to the room. This "resets" the pregnant woman (supposedly, I never bothered, since the first option seems easier)

Comment: There's also a menu that shows the currently employed dwellers in the selected room, a button for which appears in like bottom left or something. You think that can work to move the prego dwellers? If yes then could you add it to your answer?

Comment: @user1337 Interesting proposition. I'll try it the next time it happens.

Comment: Appreciated. I'll see if I beat you to it, although I'm not really in a situation that favors mass breeding at the moment.